Show that if $a>0$, then $P(X \geq \mu + a) \leq e^{-a^2/2\sigma^2}$.
Let $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Show that if $a>0$, then $P(X \geq \mu + a) \leq e^{-a^2/2\sigma^2}$.
My solution:

Define $Y = X - \mu.$
Then $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$. We want to show that
$$
P(Y \geq a) = P(X - \mu \geq a) = P(X \geq \mu + a) \leq e^{-a^2/2\sigma^2}.
$$
Let $Z=e^{tY}$ and $c=e^{ta}$. Then by Markov's inequality
$$
P(Y \geq a) = P(e^{tY} \geq e^{ta}) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}\bigl[e^{\,tY}\bigr]}{e^{\,ta}}.
$$
Since $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ its MGF is $\mathbb{E}\bigl[e^{\,tY}\bigr] = e^{\sigma^2 t^2/2}$. Hence $P(Y \geq a) \leq e^{-ta}\cdot e^{\sigma^2 t^2/2} = e^{\sigma^2 t^2/2-ta}$. To get the upper bound, we minimize the exponent with respect to $t$. Therefore, $$\min_{t>0} \left[\frac{t^2 \sigma^2}{2} \;-\; t \, a\right]=-\frac{a^2}{2\sigma^2}.$$ Hence $P(Y \geq a) \leq e^{-a^2/(2\sigma^2)}$. Now recall that $P(X \geq \mu + a) = P(Y \geq a) \leq e^{-a^2/(2\sigma^2)}$.

Is this solution correct? I'm not really sure about the minimization part but it was the best I could think of.

Looks good to me. Note that the bound you are asked to show is false.

Looks great to me. Here's another way to get a bound. $aP(Y>a)=a\int_{a}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{y^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}})dy\leq \int_{a}^{\infty}\frac{y}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{y^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}})dy=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{a^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}$ which yields you the bound $P(Y>a)\leq \frac{\sigma}{a\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{a^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}$

Very nice, thank you!

Your solution is fine. You have a factor of $2$ in the denominator of the exponent in the upper bound that is missing in the statement of your problem. But the 2 needs to be there: You can show (l'Hôpital) that
$$
\lim_{a\to+\infty}{aP(Y\ge a)\over \sigma\varphi(a/\sigma)}=1,
$$
where $\varphi(x)={1\over \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$ is the standard normal density function.
